# Solving distributional differential equation of the third order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a general solution in $ \mathcal{D}^{'}(\mathbf{R}^{1}) $ of the distributional differential equation

$$(1+x)u^{'''} = 0. $$

I studied the solution for the equation $ xu^{'} = 0 $ in the book by Keener, but I still can understand how to generalize it for the third-ordered equation.

I seek a distribution  $u$ whose action satisfies $(u, ((1+x)\phi)^{'''}) = 0$ or $ (u, \psi) = 0 $ for any test function of the form $ \psi = ((1+x)\phi)^{'''} $.

I have no idea, how to show it. It is simple but not in the sense of distributions. I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you solve the equation for classical solutions?

Comment: I must be missing something. Why can't you just integrate it? Well, there are two possibilities. Either $(1+x)=0$ or $u'''=0$. For the second case, the solution is by integration gives

$$
    u(x)= \frac{1}{2} c_{1} x^{2}+c_{2} x +c_{3}
$$
May be I am not reading it as an ode?

Comment: I admit I do not know what a "distributional differential equation" is. Must be something else. But It looked like a normal ode for me as written.